# Организация возможности редактирования и в Word, и в Excel

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, ms-word

Есть Word-документ с некоторой таблицей. Сейчас он сохранен в формате XPS и выводится в окне. По задумке должна быть кнопка для редактирования таблицы. На выбор должно быть три варианта: редактировать в Word, в Excel и в самой программе. Как это можно (и можно ли вообще) сделать?

Comment: В мире программирования нет ничего невозможого. Фактическое решение зависит от ваших требований. "Как в Word" жизни не хватит, чтобы реализовать, потому что ворд - очень сложный програмный комплекс, написаный огромной командой профессиональных разработчиков за очень много лет. С экселем то же самое.

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать официальное Api - Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, как работать с таблицами можно найти [тут](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-create-word-tables?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp). Есть ещё [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/word-processing), но это довольно низкоуровневая штука. Есть варианты проще, но это платные библиотеки.

Answer (score 0):

Для Excel есть прекрасная либа под названием [`EPPlus`](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus).